# Android FingerPaint SDK sample use as text/image highlighter

Tags: android, canvas, draw

What I want to archive is, highlight a text or an image as we do in PDF or any other doc editor.

What I am doing is, in my xml layout I have added a `TextView`, `ImageView`, `WebView` in an `RelativeLayout` and depending on the type of the contents to be displayed, I change the visibility of the one, for example if I have an image to display then I set the image Path to ImageView and set it is as visible and others as invisible.

For drawing highlight, I am trying to use Android SDK demo [FingerPaint](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java).
On Top of all these views I have `MyView`, which draws the highlight, which is from `FingerPaint` SDK demo, I have made the canvas transparent so I am able to see widgets below `MyView`.

**Questions that I have:**

- I am not able to get what is the use of `mCanvas = new
  Canvas(mBitmap);` in `onSizeChanged` method, as mCanvas is not added to view, when I remove it then old lines that i draw does not display on the screen.
- How to change the line size and make color of the line semi transparent, so that view below `MyView` is visible from the line.
- How to draw only straight lines (Vertical/Horizontal).